# Badge notifications on Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications, badge

I am trying to set badge notification on icon for my app when I recive a push notification.
I see that there are some libraries but all not works and I see that there are some codes that check manufacturer name to apply a counter on icon app.

For example, on Xiaomi smartphone, I need to open Settings > Notifications than search my app and set BadgeNotification to "enabled".

How can I do this programmatically? I am not founding a permission to set on manifest...

Answer (score -1):

Out of box android OS doesn't support badge functionality yet.
You could.use library of it is device specific. Like samsung, vivo etc

Comment: So I need to implement and use library for each specific manufacturer Samsung,Xiaomi,Vivo etc?

Comment: No need to use different library for different manufacturers. https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: I am testing this library but with my Xiaomi Android 10 not works. I am using this fix too but not works https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/wiki/Xiaomi-Device-Support

Comment: confirm that this library not works with Android 10. I am using his release and I have the same result.